# extracting raster files by matching their name with the other list of names

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a list of raster files which the dates are included in their name, and I have other list with dates. and I want to extract only the raster files which their names or dates match with my date list!
How I can do it! 
here are my codes for better understanding!

```
files               <- list.files(full.names=T, pattern=paste0("_S2_B|L8_sr_"))
rootName            <- substring(basename(files),1,7)
date_raster         <- as.Date(rootName,'%Y%j')
```

then here I get the date names of each raster file like this,

```
[1] "2013-04-15" "2013-04-15" "2013-04-15" "2013-04-15" "2013-04-15" "2013-04-15" "2013-04-24" "2013-04-24" "2013-04-24" "2013-04-24"
 [11] "2013-04-24" "2013-04-24" "2013-05-01" "2013-05-01" "2013-05-01"
```

and I only wanna extract files that their date names match with these dates!

```
humid_date                 <- raster_humid$date


[1] "2014-05-13" "2014-07-23" "2014-09-02" "2014-09-18" "2015-01-31" "2015-09-12" "2015-09-21" "2015-12-10" "2015-12-28" "2016-01-14" "2016-04-13"
[12] "2016-05-23" "2016-05-25" "2016-07-12" "2016-07-22" "2016-07-25"
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you have a list of all dates in the filenames and a list of dates you want to select. In this case you can use `which(x %in% y)` as shown below. Since I was too lazy to reformat your example data (sorry) I have created some myself and hope that they sufficiently resemble yours. I hope this is what you are looking for. (you might need to convert your `date` type into `character` for matching)

```
files <- paste0(9:1, "file")
dates_files <- substr(files, 1,1)
select_dates <- as.character(c(1,3,5))

files[which(dates_files %in% select_dates)]
#[1] "5file" "3file" "1file"
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Just realized that you could probably limit the selection of files alread in `list.files()`.  If there is only one date in each filename you could try `list.files( ... ,  pattern = paste(select_dates, collapse = "|"))`. Or does that collide with other selection criteria?

Comment: its also a good idea! but I think it will be a bit complicated as I already have another criteria to limit the selection, then I am limiting again the selection by these dates! :)

Comment: Alright, was not sure if this could be applied to your case, just wanted to mention it. At least the proposed solution works for you.